# How to use axios.post method for a cURL command? (Or fix status code: 415)

Tags: node.js, curl, post, axios, spotify

**We need to run the axios.post equivalent for following cURL command in nodeJS:**

```
  curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM4Zj...Y0MzE=" -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=NgAagA...NUm_SHo https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

**My Approach:**

```
axios.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  refresh_token: 'NgAagA...NUm_SHo',
  header: {
    Authorization: 'Basic ZjM4Zj...Y0MzE=',
  }
}).then((resAxios) => {
  console.log(resAxios.data)
  spotifyResult = resAxios.data;
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

**Above code returns the following error in reponse:**

```
statusCode: 415,
statusMessage: 'Unsupported Media Type'
```

**Format:**

`refresh_token` should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

`Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>`

**Refer the *'Authorization Code Flow'* for the cURL command, here:**

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

*Feel free to provide with any other variant, i.e., instead of using axios. I preferred it, since it parses the fetched data as well. Please provide with the code to parse it with, if so. I'm a 'beginner' beginner.*

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I haven't used the proper syntax. I don't know how to include request body parameters.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data

Comment: Or maybe it has something to do with `'content-type'`

Comment: I tried this approach. The server didn't start and returned, `ReferenceError: FormData is not defined'.

Comment: @vcboi Have you tried sending `content-type` inside `header`?

Comment: @zx01 Yep, I tried putting it next to `Authorization` as `'content-type': 'application/json'`

Comment: The `ReferenceError: FormData is not defined` was in response to suggestion given by @MarcStroebel

Comment: @vcboi Try using `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.

Comment: FormData is a npm package, did you install it? https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data

Comment: @zx01 No good. Returned with the same error. On a side-note, why do we put `content-type` in quotation marks, while all the others like `Authorization` are not in quotation marks?

Comment: @MarcStroebel Oh. I wasn't aware. Just did. Returned with the same error. It's actually a 100 lined or so long response. Is there anything specific that I should mention in the question, apart from the fact that it returns with status code 415?

Comment: @vcboi Because of the hyphen in between. Hehe. We can put double quotes for other properties as well but its not required. Btw, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947586/415-coming-back-from-requesting-a-token-spotify-api/48947993). May be this could help.

Comment: another approach, try this sample: https://gist.github.com/akexorcist/ea93ee47d39cf94e77802bc39c46589b

Comment: @zx01 Alright, got that. Trying the solution on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the folks: [Manuel Spigolon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309466/manuel-spigolon), [zx01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13917177/zx01), [Mark Stroebel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4445625/marc-stroebel), [Łukasz Szewczak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947993/14597561), [ponury-kostek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947993/14597561), [Jakub Luczak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8802506/jakub-luczak), [Gerardo Gonzalez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57857453/14597561) :)

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947993/14597561) answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947586/415-coming-back-from-requesting-a-token-spotify-api/48947993) link, as provided by [@zx01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13917177/zx01) in the comments to the question.

**Final code, tailored to the needs:**

```
axios({
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    method: "post",
    params: {
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
      //grant_type: "client_credentials", //This works as well.
        refresh_token: 'AQAw95rH0...CnWBE'
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization:'Basic MWQ4Z...dhYmU=',
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },

}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

*However, the following syntax doesn't seems to work.*
It again returns with status code 415: Unsupported Media Type.

```
axios.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", null, {
    params: {
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
      //grant_type: "client_credentials", //This doesn't work either.
        refresh_token: 'AQAw95rH0...CnWBE'
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization:'Basic MWQ4Z...dhYmU=',
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

It'd be dope if somebody could fix the above code, and reason as to why we're getting that error.

Also notice there is a quomma ',', next to the closing curly braces  that packs the 'headers' property.

Comment: Please try this one because its working for me in postman. Replace `grant_type: "refresh_token"` with `grant_type: "client_credentials"`

Comment: @zx01 Yes! Thank you so much. It did work. Updating the answer.

Comment: @zx01 How did you figure, that `"refresh_token"` can also be replaced? And that it can be replaced to `"client_credentials"`?

Comment: `grant_type: client_credentials` doesn't work in the second code sample.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I didn't notice that the two codes are different. I thought both were same. The problem with the second code is that axios.post takes three parameters(url, data and config). Since we are not sending any body/data so we have to pass null as second argument. And the third argument will be the params, header, etc.

Comment: Even in the initial code of yours I failed to notice that you were not passing three parameters inside `axios.post()`

Comment: @zx01 Ohhh. Alright. I wasn't aware, thank you for letting me know. How do we pass null parameter? Simply `null`?

Comment: Yes. Simply null as second parameter.